# how to move files on reboot in nsis

Tags: nsis, reboot

i need to move files on reboot from source to destination. tried below 3 methods and all have failed

```
IfFileExists  "$Temp\test.dll" 0 new_installation 
    StrCpy $ALREADY_INSTALLED 1
        new_installation:
        SetOverwrite on
        !insertmacro InstallLib DLL $ALREADY_INSTALLED REBOOT_PROTECTED "$Temp\test.dll" "$WINDIR\test.dll" "$WINDIR"

System::Call "kernel32::MoveFileEx(t '$TEMP\test.dll', t '$WINDIR\test.dll', i 5)"

Rename /REBOOTOK '$TEMP\test.dll' `$WINDIR\test.dll`
```

Comment: Which file are you actually trying to replace?

Answer (score 0):

We confirmed elsewhere that your direct call to MoveFileEx succeeds. This should mean that the rename operation has been recorded in the registry. You can confirm this with the [PendMoves tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pendmoves) from SysInternals. That same page also provides a MoveFile tool you can try.

Assuming the operation has been recorded, you should investigate the reasons the file operation might fail during boot:

- One or both files are read-only.
- The security descriptor (ACL) blocks the move and/or delete operation.
- The file you are trying to replace is a [protected system file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-windows-file-protection-feature-db28f515-6512-63d1-6178-982ed2022ffb).
- File is locked by the system or a driver.

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/481404/658), Process Monitor boot logging is active before the rename operation begins so you could use it to see if it provides any clues as to why the operation fails...